# which one is the correct option for the particle from region potentia=0 to potential=-Vo

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Consider the potential field V(x, y) which is 0 and -Vo (Vo > 0) respectively in the regions
of y greater and less than zero . Let θ and θ' be the angles of incidence and refraction of
the particle with the y-axis at the point of incidence as it crosses the x-axis . The ratio
sin(θ) / sin(θ ') is given (in terms of Δ = Vo / E) by

[image]

(a)√(1+2Vο/E)
(b)√(1+Vο/E)
(c)1+Vο/E
(d)1+2Vο/E

I am using snell's law

nsinθ=n'sinθ'

sinθ/sinθ'=v/v'

but it gives wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the formulation of Snell's law for massive particles.

Due to conservation of momentum parallel to the interface, we obtain Snell's law which states that:

$$p\sin\theta = p'\sin\theta',$$

where p is the momentum of the particle. This can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta'}=\frac{p'}{p} $$

For massless particles, the group velocity is given by $v=\frac{dE}{dp}=\frac{E}{p}$. The velocity is thus inversely proportional to the momentum (for a fixed energy). This leads to the well known forulation of Snell's law for massless particles:

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta'}=\frac{p'}{p}=\frac{v}{v'} $$

For massive particles on the other hand, the group velocity is $v=\frac{dE}{dp}=\frac{d\left(\frac{1}{2m}p^2\right)}{dp}=\frac{p}{m}$. The velocity is in this case thus proportional to the momentum. This leads to:

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta'}=\frac{p'}{p}=\frac{v'}{v}. $$

Using the correct version of Snell's law will lead to the correct result.

Comment: @PRoy This is what Newton got wrong with his corpuscles which he assumed had a mass, so you are in good company.